# Minimum number of steps in which these people can rearrange themselves?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, strategy

5 persons numbered 1 to 5 are standing in a row at 5 spots.

1   2   3   4   5

Any person can call another person among the remaining 4. When someone calls someone else, the person who was called comes on the adjacent spot toward his side, **on the same side of the person that called him**, and then the others rearrange themselves accordingly. (see example ahead)

Now the first and last spot are special. After each time someone calls someone else, subsequent to the rearrangement, **the two persons standing on the first and last spot teleport to each others’ spots!**

For example, if person 2 calls person 5, and after rearrangement and teleportation, person 1 calls person 4, these **two steps** can be represented in the following way:

[image]

They can’t call anyone who’s already adjacent to them of course, since they’re already on their side, and it won't be counted as a step.

What is the minimum number of steps that’ll take for the people for going

**from:**

**1    2    3    4    5**

**to:**

**5    4    3    2    1**

NOTE: I'm new at creating puzzles, I might have missed some important detail, so please bear with me. I'll try to respond promptly to the comments and make any required changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it can be done in 3 calls (and 3 corresponding switches).

```
1 2 3 4 5     
              (2 calls 4)
5 2 4 3 1     (4 moves next to 2, then 1 and 5 switch) 
              (5 calls 4)
1 4 2 3 5     (4 moves next to 5, then 5 and 1 switch again) 
              (4 calls 3)
5 4 3 2 1     (3 moves next to 4, and 5 and 1 switch one last time)
```

A brilliant observation from Tyler Seacrest

> Note that there is no one move solution, because after one move, either 5 or 1 is in the correct ending position. Then, after another move, the 5 or 1 is no longer in the correct ending position. So there is no two-move solution either.

Comment: This is what I have written on a post-it, and I can't think of how to do it better!

Comment: Haha, beat me to it for sure. I blame my mangled finger, but I came up with the same solution.

Comment: I'm also keen on seeing if this can be bettered.

Comment: Note that, although there is no one move solution, after one move, either 5 or 1 is in the correct ending position.   Then, after another move, the 5 or 1 is no longer in the correct ending position.  So there is no two-move solution.

Comment: ^ that makes sense.
@CodeNewbie, This seems to be the solution. I guess I can make it more complex by adding more people, or more weird contraptions like the teleportation thing. Any suggestions on having such a variation that is more elegant and not too complex?

Comment: @thereisnospoon Just use MD5 teleportation (or some other hash function). It will make it impossible without a computer :D

Answer (score 1):

> 3 steps.

Like this:

> 12345 -> 52431 -> 14235 -> 54321

or because of the symmetry:

> 12345 -> 53241 -> 13425 -> 54321

---

Edit: if there are more people, we can do this (omitting the first and the last end):

$2, 3, ..., n-1$
$n-1, 2, 3, ..., n-2$

Now that we've managed to put $n-1$ in its right place, we can drag others next to it.

After putting numbers from 2 to $n-2$ ($n-3$ numbers) into their right place in $n-4$ more moves, we'll have made $n-3$ in total. If $n-3$ is odd ($n$ is even), it can be done. Otherwise we start with the ones from 5 to $n-2$ ($n-6$ numbers) in $n-6$ more moves, then finish the 432 part with another 3 moves, making $n-2$ moves in total:

234
324
342
432

or

234
243
423
432

Comment: For the general case, what if involving the first and last spots in the rearrangements makes a difference and reduces the number of steps? Your algorithm is valid, and works for 5 people I understand, but I was just wondering if involving first and last spot people make any difference.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Edited accordingly to make it clearer.